# How do I get distinct values from the table along with the count of how many rows there are containing that value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

IN SQL (and if possible how to write it in Laravel Eloquent), if there are 10 MySQL rows having value IN', 4 rows having value 'US', 7 rows having value 'FR'; I want the query result to be three rows:

1. IN | 10
2. US | 4
3. FR | 7

Comment: `select country, count(*) from my_table group by country`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name, count(*) as c FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name ORDER BY c DESC
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer it worked but I think it should be count(*) without the whitespace in between as that gave an error

Answer (score 1):

```
Model::query()->groupBy('country_name')->select('counrty_name',DB::raw('COUNT(1)'))->get()
```